# Is there a way to build a fuzzy logic in MySQL to compare two tables and then add values in a table?

Tags: mysql, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I have two tables in MySQL DB:- TABLE1 having rows and columns like

```
id      name
5225    1-800-FLOWERS.COM, INC.
5226    10X Genomics Inc
5227    111 Inc
5228    17 Education & Technology Group Inc
5229    1Life Healthcare Inc
```

TABLE2 as

```
id      name
5225    1-800-FLOWERS.COM, INC.
5226    10X Genomics Inc PVT LTD
5227    111 Inc
5228    17 Education & Technology Group Inc
5229    1Life Healthcare Inc
```

If we look at the `name` column in both tables almost all the names are matching however in TABLE1 there is 10X Genomics Inc and in TABLE2 there is 10X Genomics Inc PVT LTD. I am trying to build a logic which can handle cases like these and then add the names and ids from TABLE2 to TABLE1. Also if a name from TABLE2 is not present in TABLE1 then it should be added.

How do I achieve this? I have worked previously in SQL however haven't encountered such a scenario till now, please help me out!

Comment: You need in 2 queries. First will be `INSERT .. ODKU` and second `INSERT .. WHERE NOT EXISTS`. I assume that `id` is PK in both tables.

Comment: @Akina thanks for the immediate response, yes id is PK in both tables.. the id in TABLE1 is also autoincremental, also what does ODKU mean? will it handle the fuzzy logic? because values "10X Genomics Inc PVT LTD" and "10X Genomics Inc" are both the same it should not create a new value in the table; this is where fuzzy matching comes

Comment: *what does ODKU mean?* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html *values "10X Genomics Inc PVT LTD" and "10X Genomics Inc" are both the same it should not create a new value in the table* (a) sync data updating this value in A (or, maybe, B); (b) do not alter valus staying them different. Select one of..

Comment: @Akina thanks a lot for your help! I will try to do this, if possible could you please post an answer for the same?